# Import JSON to Flask template

Tags: json, templates, flask

I'm passing JSON

```
{
 "name": "Jo",
 "surname": "Sin",
 "market": "US",
 "date": "2020-07-07T00:00:00",
 "contactPerson": {
   "name": "Jan Kowalski",
   "position": "Nikt",
   "address": "ul. Kolorowa 123",
   "phone": "736537362",
   "fax": "827283738",
   "email": "koko@ko.pl"
 },
 "secondContactPerson": {
   "name": "Anna Mark",
   "position": "buk",
   "address": "ul. Nowowiejska 37a",
   "phone": "27637222342",
   "fax": "347484748",
   "email": "lala@la.pl"
 },
 "representatives": [
   {
     "name": "Wojciech Makowski",
     "title": "master"
   }
 ],
 "customerRepresentatives": [
   {
     "name": "George Soros",
     "title": "bogacz"
   }
 ]
}
```

```
templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./templates/")
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
TEMPLATE_FILE = "pdf_template.html"
template = templateEnv.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILE)
html = template.render(context_dict)
```

to Flask template and I would like to modify it for example from date I would like to get just day and month. I would like to list all representatives and more. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{ json.date.strftime('%A') }}
```